# How do I remove the whitespace after each comma in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am struggling with removing spaces in an arraylist of strings.

Say the user input is as follows: "I walked my dog", my code outputs this:

```
[I, walked, my, dog]
```

I want it to have no spaces as such:

```
[I,walked,my,dog]
```

I tried to remove whitespace on each individual string before I add it to the arrayList, but the output still has the spaces.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> userWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> SplituserWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Please enter your phrase: ");
    userWords.add(input.nextLine());
    
    for (int index = 0; index < userWords.size(); index++) {
      String[] split = userWords.get(index).split("\\s+");
      for (String word : split) {
        word.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        SplituserWords.add(word);
      }
      System.out.println(SplituserWords);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest just taking advantage of the built-in `Arrays#toString()` method here:

```java
String words = input.nextLine();
String output = Arrays.toString(words.split(" ")).replace(" ", "");
System.out.println(output);  // [I,walked,my,dog]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `System.out.println(SplituserWords);`, you are implicitly calling `ArrayList#toString()` which generates the list's string and that includes spaces after commas.

You can instead generates your own string output, for example with:

```
System.out.println("[" + String.join(",", SplituserWords) + "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `List`, it will do it for you.

```java
String input = "I walked my dog";
List<String> SplitUserWords = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
String output = SplitUserWords.toString().replace(" ", "");
System.out.println(output); //[I,walked,my,dog]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to remove whitespace on each individual string before I add it to the arrayList, but the output still has the spaces.

That won't work because that isn't the problem.  The issue is that it is the `list implementation` that formats the output for you inserts a space after each comma. It does this in the `toString()` method.  To avoid having to explicitly call `replace` each time you can also do it like this by overidding `toString()` when you create your List.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(List.of("I","walked","my", "dog")) {
     @Override
     public String toString() {
        // use super to call the overidden method to format the string
        // then remove the spaces and return the new String
        return super.toString().replace(" ", "");
     }
 };

System.out.println(myList);
myList.addAll(List.of("and", "then","fed", "my", "cat"));
System.out.println(myList);
```

prints

```
[I,walked,my,dog]
[I,walked,my,dog,and,then,fed,my,cat]
```

You can also subclass `ArrayList` as follows.  Here I have added the three constructors that `ArrayList` implements.  **Note** that is is a somewhat *extreme solution* and may not be worth it for occasionally reformatting of the output.  I included it for your consideration.

```
class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    public MyArrayList() {
        super();
    }
    public MyArrayList(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }
    
    public MyArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return super.toString().replace(" ", "");
    }
}
```

And it would work like so.

```
MyArrayList<String> myList = new MyArrayList<>(List.of("This", "is", "a","test."));
System.out.println(myList);
```

prints

```
[This,is,a,test.]
```